# mount secrets for jupyterhub on kubernetes with Helm

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, kubernetes-helm, jupyterhub, docker-secrets

I am new to Kubernetes and Helm.
I deployed a jupyterhub pod on Kubernetes (on GCP) following this line

https://zero-to-jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/stable/jupyterhub/installation.html

- First, I managed to get it working with simple configuration and in order to interact with GCS from the notebooks I am currently uploading a keyfile.json for each user and using environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS.
- I would like to mount the keyfile as secret in the values.yaml. How could I do that ?
  Basically, I would like to get rid of uploading manually the file for each user and have it mounted automatically through the yaml file.

Thanks

Comment: You can mount the secret directly as a data volume on the pod. Here is a [document](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#using-secrets). you'll have to run the pods again

Comment: Thank you that actually what I needed

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get it working by adding this in yaml file.
keyfile.json was created as secret named gcsfs-creds with cubectl secrets.

```
   extraEnv:
    GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS: "/etc/secrets/keyfile.json"
   storage:
    extraVolumes:
      - name: gcsfs-creds
        secret:
          secretName: gcsfs-creds
          items:
            - key: keyfile.json
              path: keyfile.json
    extraVolumeMounts:
      - name: gcsfs-creds
        mountPath: "/etc/secrets"
        readOnly: true
```